# How to have an object access its invoking object's variables and modify them?

Tags: java, oop, parameters, constructor

Say I had a 2d side view type game. In this game I have sprites and other objects. The sprite jumps when you click spacebar. The jumping and other things are affected by gravity.  I'd have a `Gravity` class that requires the parameters of an x & y coordinate of the object it's affecting. When its constructed from the `Sprite` class, I'd give it the x and y of the sprites location as parameters. Then, the gravity class does the necessary math and now has a modified x & y coordinate. How can I update the old x & y in the `Sprite` class (which is the invoking class) to the new coordinate pair calculated by `Gravity` (the object which needs to modify the variables in `Sprite`)?

**Extra info:**
The x & y variables can't be static. This is all on one thread currently(with the exception of the graphics thread that draws). I could make more threads if needed. I have a swing Timer in the gravity class that starts when the object is created, and is used to calculate the coordinate as an effect of time, velocity, acceleration, etc.

**Gravity Class Code:**

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Gravity implements ActionListener { 

    final double gravAccel = -32.174;
    double velocity; // in FPS
    double angle; // in degrees
    double x; // centralized location of object in feet
    double y; // centralized location in feet
    double time = 0;
    Timer timer;
    boolean fired = true;
    Point start;

    public Gravity(double x, double y, double velocity, double angle, Point start) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.angle = angle;
        this.start = start;
        initTimer();
    }



    void initTimer() {
        timer = new Timer(10, this);
        timer.start();
    }   


    public void fire(double velocity, double angle) {
        //timer.start();
        x = (velocity * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle))) * time + start.getX();
        y = 0.5 * gravAccel * Math.pow(time, 2) + (velocity * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))) * time + start.getY();
        System.out.println("Time:" + time + "          " + x + "," + y);

    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        time = time + 0.01;
        if (fired == true) {
            fire(velocity, angle);
        }

    }
}
```

**Sprite:**

```
public class Sprite {
    double x = 10; //how can I modify these from gravity
    double y = 10;
    Sprite() {
       new Gravity(x, y, 100, 45, new Point(0,0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your sprite class calling it? Can't you just get the x of the new gravity and y of the new gravity and set the sprites x and y location to the gravity classes?

Comment: @RileyCarney do you mean with getters/setters? Yes I could, but the timer is in the gravity class, so I'd have to create a new timer in my Sprite class that is synced with the Gravity timer and call the get() in the actionPreformed() method of the Sprite timer in order to update Sprite's x & y. That doesn't seem very efficient or clean. Shouldn't I really only need one Timer for the Sprite object to work? (I could move the timer to the Sprite class, but then I'd have to add Timers to all game Objects, isn't it easier to have a timer built into Gravity so that its applicable for everything?)

Comment: Do you have a main `client` class or something that is where your game runs? You should have a class where everything "comes together" in a sense, where your main game loops runs etc.

Comment: @RileyCarney not really. This game is just for fun, I know nothing about game programming. I was just experimenting really.  I could try to write something like that. The only class I have currently that resembles a "client" is my class called Program (which includes void main()) where I start the JFrame thread which then adds a JPanel which initializes the Sprite which as you know initializes Gravity. To sum that up: just a messy chain of class calling and initialization starting from Program.

Comment: I believe that is where you should put your timer thread, however, I haven't done much programming with swing in Java, so I'm not sure if it is the correct thing to do. Personally, I would have whenever the character jumps, run the timer and apply physics to him, but if he is not jumping, have no timer running, as when I read the javadoc of Timer, it said `Timer tasks should complete quickly. If a timer task takes excessive time to complete, it "hogs" the timer's task execution thread.`

Comment: @RileyCarney okay thanks. That's interesting, i clearly haven't been using Timer correctly. I'm also guessing I shouldn't be using java.awt.Timer for non-graphics related segments of my program.

Comment: Yes, you should probably have a game class that acts as a controller (take a look into MVC) which would have the game timer.

Comment: Glad I was right on that front, would like to clarify however on the timer thread. You can use that wherever you want to, I just think it would be a better practice to follow up on all the player's graphic calculations on one thread, instead of making timers for each class. Also I was checking out the `Timer` javadoc, and it said you may want to look at `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, as it is pretty sweet.

Comment: @RileyCarney you are probably right, but the name alone is making me nervous! Sounds a bit complex for my level ;). I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a reference to the Sprite in Gravity:

```
private Sprite;
public Gravity(double x, double y, double velocity, double angle, Point start, Sprite sprite) {
   this.sprite = sprite;
   ...
}
```

and just pass this from Sprite when you create it:

```
Sprite() {
   new Gravity(x, y, 100, 45, new Point(0,0), this);
}
```

Comment: Clever! Just what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You could just make `x` and `y` public:

```
public double x = 10;
public double y = 10;
```

And then access them directly from the sprite class.

Comment: Yes, I could. But, that would still require me to have some sort of timer in my Sprite class to get/set the x & y from gravity so that defeats the purpose. The question title specifically says have the object modify its invoking object not the other way around.

Comment: Bad advice. Doing that will leave the potential for all code to change those values which should be changed in a very controlled manner. The access doesn't matter anyway. Why wouldn't they be able to use getters and setters?

Comment: Then make them `protected` and add getters and setters - which is still my main concept: to make them accessible by the `Gravity` class.

Comment: Look at Ashwin Gupta's reply @Majora320, he wants something different.

Comment: @RileyCarney I was replying to ChiefTwoPencils, I should have \@mentioned him.